When pressed on menu item, chrome opens a help page
A new tab opens on my browser whenever I press an element in the menu on attachment. It becomes really annoying because it opens lots of new tabs in my chrome browser whenever I press an item on the left menu. Is it possible to deactivate this?



Does the problem go away if you temporarily disable all of the non-bundled plugins and restart the IDE? File | Settings | Plugins | ⚙ | Disable all downloaded plugins

The problem still persists. I disabled all non bundled plugins and restarted but still popups occur. @Koyasha

This looks like the help page of that menu entry. Have you checked if your F1 key is physically stuck, or if some automation software (e.g. AutoHotkey) on your computer is automatically sending F1 key presses on mouse click?

@LokiRagnarok Yeah that was the problem. I forgot that I was using AutoHotkey. There was one shortcut that maps to HELP in that script. This caused problem. Thank you. If you make this a proper answer, I can mark it as solution.
